# How can Overwrite python output?

Tags: python, overwrite

I have a random output on python. And I want to organize the output by putting a comma between every 5 character of output
How can I do that?

```
import random, string
length = 10
chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits


rnd = random.SystemRandom()

print(''.join(rnd.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
```

Comment: What format is your data in? A list? A string?

Comment: please provide some sample code, there are a bunch of different ways this can be done, it'll be easier to answer with more to work with

Comment: I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter in a loop. When it reaches the given value (in this case 4), put a comma.
I think it would be easier to read the data from a file and when iterating over it, then put the comma.

Comment: As you write an answer, please show your solution in a small exampel. I know you are new and you can't leave a comment, that's why I didnt downvote your post.